# MongoDB Not Sending Responses Through Postman?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

Oh man, this API project is a real huge pain. I got all of these endpoints working yesterday, but as soon as I stared trying to add data to a collection in the database (via Mongo shell), all of a sudden my requests are hanging up. Here is my server:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Character = require('./api/models/characterListModels'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect({ useNewUrlParser: true }, 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/streetfighterdb');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var routes = require('./api/routes/characterListRoutes')
routes(app);

app.listen(port);

console.log('Street Fighter RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
```

Here is my controller

```
        'use strict';
    
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Character = mongoose.model('Characters')
    
    exports.list_all_characters = function (req, res) {
        Character.find({}, function (error, character) {
            if (error) {
                res.send(error);
            } else {
            res.json(character)
            }
        })
    }
    
    exports.create_a_character = function (req, res) {
        var new_character = new Character(req.body);
        new_character.save(function (error, character) {
            if (error) {
                res.send(error);
            }
            res.json(character);
        });
    }

exports.get_a_character = function (req, res) {
    Character.findById(req.params.characterId, function (error, character) {
        if (error) {
            res.send(error);
        }
        res.json(character);
    });
}

exports.update_a_character = function (req, res) {
    Character.findByIdAndUpdate({
        _id: req.params.characterId
    }, req.body, {
        new: true
    }, function (error, character) {
        if (error) {
            res.send(error);
        }
        res.json(character);
    });
}

exports.delete_a_character = function (req, res) {
    Character.deleteOne({
        _id: req.params.characterId
    }, function (error, character) {
        if (error) {
            res.send(error);
        }
        if (!error) {
            res.json('Character Successfully Deleted');
        }
    })
}
```

Here is my router

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
var characterList = require('../controllers/characterListController');

app.route('/characters')
.get(characterList.list_all_characters)
.post(characterList.create_a_character);

app.route('/characters/:characterId')
.get(characterList.get_a_character)
.put(characterList.update_a_character)
.delete(characterList.delete_a_character);
};
```

Here is my Model

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var characterSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Characters', characterSchema);
```

Now I have tried a few things.

1. Removed the specific response and just added a generic `res.send('success')` and it worked.
2. I also replaced the `{}` in the `Character.find()` method with a `[]` and it worked (responded with an empty object). For some reason though, none of the other endpoints return responses.
3. Added a `console.log(res)` and a `console.log(req)` and got the logs in the console.

What is going on here? Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referenced by mongoose [offical docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options...', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

You are passing the options as first argument, please replace it as offical docs example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is ridiculous, but it turns out that passing the { useNewUrlParser: true } broke it.